# span tag onclick to call a code behind method

Tags: c#, asp.net, onclick, html

Hai guys,

How to make a span tag behave exactly like an asp:button (ie) using its onclick method to call a codebehind method..

```
<span onclick="MyPageMethod()"></span>
```

I know linkbuttons can do it for me,but my question is can span tag do it for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having a span tag be clickable is generally a Very Bad Idea. It's bad for UI and it's bad for accessibility because it's not something that a user would expect. You should use anchor tags and buttons if it's clickable.

But to answer your question: Yes, it's definitely possible to do something *like* this! You just have to mimic what the LinkButton control does.

To get the JavaScript code that does an ASP.NET postback you need to call:

```
Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference()
```

More info is on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153112.aspx).

Then you have to write code on the page that handles the postback and calls `MyPageMethod()`.

Comment: I was dynamically creating span tag and assigning it's onclick using span.onClick = which didn't work at all in ie....  changed the createElement to create an img instead and now it works.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Call __dopostback method in javascript.
See followings:
http://urenjoy.blogspot.com/2009/02/add-dynamic-buttons-and-handle-click.html
http://aspalliance.com/895_Understanding_the_JavaScript___doPostBack_Function
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200815112309/http://geekswithblogs.net/mnf/archive/2005/11/04/59081.aspx)